# SQL ISNULL() Query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
update a set PROPERTYADDRESS = ISNULL(a.PROPERTYADDRESS, b.PROPERTYADDRESS)
    from data a
    join data b
    on a.PARCELID = b.PARCELID
    and a.[ID] <> b.[ID]    
    where a.PROPERTYADDRESS is null
```

In Oracle SQL for the given code it is showing me error:

> Error starting at line : 25 in command -

```
update a   
set PROPERTYADDRESS = ISNULL(a.PROPERTYADDRESS, b.PROPERTYADDRESS)
    from data a
    join data b
    on a.PARCELID = b.PARCELID
    and a.[ID] <> b.[ID]    
    where a.PROPERTYADDRESS is null
```

> Error at Command Line : 27 Column : 5
>
> Error report -
> SQL Error: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>
> 933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
>
> *Cause:
>
> *Action:

Basically I think its is not taking ISNULL() as a function need help to solve this

Comment: This is the list of all Oracle built in functions: [Single-Row Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Single-Row-Functions.html#GUID-B93F789D-B486-49FF-B0CD-0C6181C5D85C). It doesn't contain `isnull`. Looks like you need a `coalesce` but it's just a guess as long as you didn't describe your intent

Answer (score 2):

1. `[]` are not valid syntax in Oracle's SQL dialect;
2. Joins in an `UPDATE` are also not valid Oracle syntax (without a sub-query); and
3. `ISNULL` is not a valid Oracle function (and there is no point using `ISNULL(a.PROPERTYADDRESS, b.PROPERTYADDRESS)` as you already filter where `a.PROPERTYADDRESS is null` so you know what the `a` value will be).

You can use:

```sql
MERGE INTO data a
USING data b
ON (   a.PARCELID =  b.PARCELID
   AND a.ID       <> b.ID       )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET   a.PROPERTYADDRESS = b.PROPERTYADDRESS
  WHERE a.PROPERTYADDRESS IS NULL
  AND   b.PROPERTYADDRESS IS NOT NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/I5YP5ip2)

Answer (score 1):

ISNULL() function is specific to SQL Server and is not supported in Oracle. You can use ISNULL() equivalent [NVL function in Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions131.htm#SQLRF00684)

```
    update (select a.PROPERTYADDRESS, b.PROPERTYADDRESS as NEW_PROPERTYADDRESS
    from data a
    join data b on a.PARCELID = b.PARCELID and a.ID <> b.ID
    where a.PROPERTYADDRESS is null)
    set PROPERTYADDRESS = NVL(PROPERTYADDRESS, NEW_PROPERTYADDRESS);
```

Comment: Or ANSI equivalent `coalesce`, that can also handle multiple arguments and works in all modern DBMS.

Comment: Yup, You are right :)